# Gerrit: same Change-Id for different commits in different branches

Tags: git, gerrit

maybe a simple question but I'm not sure how to proceed without messing up my Gerrit changes.

I have a patch on a given branch of a project, with a given Change-Id in Gerrit. What happens if I cherry-pick this change on a different branch, and then submit it in Gerrit (hence using the same Change-Id)? What will happen to the Gerrit change?

I read from here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-same-change-id-in-multiple-changes.html that Gerrit rejects the same Change-Id in case one of the predecessors has it, but in my case, this wouldn't be the case as I'm cherry-picking on a different branch.

Comment: Then Gerrit knows that the two changes on different branches are related and labels them as `Cherry-Picks`. If they are on the same branch, Gerrit rejects the push of the second change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem in this case, that's the way cherry-picks work in Gerrit. You can use the same Change-Id in different branches or repositories.

See more details [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html#change-upload).